# Find file and change permissions, ignore directories

Tags: find, aix

I am trying to write a find command that searches for file by a specific user in a directory and changes those permissions only. At the moment I am using the following:

```
ssh ${DEST_SERV} "find ${DEST_LOCATION} -type f -user a_user -exec chmod 644 {} \;"
```

This works OK, but causes the following issues when any sub directory is attempted to be parsed that is not owned by the user executing the command.

**find: 0652-081 cannot change directory to /usr/local/application/download/sub_directory:
  : The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.**

Is there a way that I can modify this to check only the named directory and users files, and ignore any sub directories also in there?

Comment: You don't have to change anything, only suppress stderr: `find ... 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

Lorinczy has a valid point.  If it is just the message that bothers you, just send it to /dev/null.  But, there is a bigger issue too that might be what you wanting to solve and that is if there are directories, you don't want to waste time going down those directories.

The answer to your question is -prune.  However, for me, it is very hard to figure out how to use it.  Here is an example.  I created some files and if I just do find, I find three files:

```
find . -name a -print
./a
./b/a
./c/a
```

If I add -prune to not go down directories that match [a-z], then I get:

```
find . -type d -name '[a-z]' -prune -o -name a -print
./a
```

or

```
find . -type d -regex '\./.*' -prune -o -name a -print
./a
```

If, instead, you want to go down directories that the user can go down and not go down directories that you can not go down, you could do that via find but it would be a long complicated command using -perm to determine "by hand" directories the user can go down and then -prune the ones that the user does not permission to search.

Comment: Thank you @Lorinczy and Pedz, I have decided to suppress stderr using your suggestion and it seems to be working how I want it too!